# Django: Verbose name of related model not translated

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I am using ugettext to translate a Category model's verbose_name. This works fine in admin when adding new objects, however, when using Category as in a one-to-many relationship with Post, the Category's verbose_name is neither translated in the list filter nor the change form of Post.

How can I correct this?

Comment: Did you set the `verbose_name` of your `ForeignKey` field in your `Post` class?

Comment: (Actually, I did and was confused why this wouldn't show up. Solved, see below)

Answer (score 4):

I just checked the official docs on [Verbose field names](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names). `ForeignKey` does not not accept the `verbose_name` positional argument.

I think what [fviktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204737/fviktor) tried to suggest was to set the `verbose_name` attribute in your model's `Meta` class:

```
class Category(Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _lazy(u'Category')
        verbose_name_plural = _lazy(u'Categories')
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it: Passing verbose_name=_('Category') keyword argument when adding the ForeignKey field.